# Get error "Cannot redirect to the authorization endpoint, the configuration may be missing or invalid" while using authority url in password flow

Tags: authorization, openid-connect, .net-6.0, openiddict

I want to use password flow in order to authenticate my MVC resource server by a separate auth server.

Currently, Token can be made directly by calling token endpoint, but when I open a  secured MVC action, It throws me

> Cannot redirect to the authorization endpoint, the configuration may be missing or invalid

It is clear that auth server is looking at the Authorization endpoint, but what I wondering is, how to implement it without that endpoint.

My auth server configuration is :

```
AddServer(options =>
        {
            // Enable the token endpoint.
            options.SetTokenEndpointUris("/token");
            // Enable the password flow.
            options.AllowPasswordFlow()
                .AllowRefreshTokenFlow();


            //// Encryption and signing of tokens

            options.AddDevelopmentEncryptionCertificate()
                .AddDevelopmentSigningCertificate();
            // Register the ASP.NET Core host and configure the ASP.NET Core options.
            options.UseAspNetCore()
                .EnableTokenEndpointPassthrough()
                .DisableTransportSecurityRequirement();


            //Disable encryption to Debug purposes 
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
                options.DisableAccessTokenEncryption();


            options.SetRefreshTokenLifetime(
                TimeSpan.FromDays(int.Parse(config.GetSection("OpenId:RefreshTokenExpireFromDay").Value)));
            options.SetAccessTokenLifetime(
                TimeSpan.FromHours(int.Parse(config.GetSection("OpenId:AccessTokenExpireFromHour").Value)));

            options.DisableRollingRefreshTokens();
            options.UseReferenceRefreshTokens();

           // options.SetIssuer(new Uri("http://localhost:8001"));

        })
        // Register the OpenIddict validation components.
        .AddValidation(options =>
        {
            // Import the configuration from the local OpenIddict server instance.
            options.UseLocalServer();

            // Register the ASP.NET Core host.
            options.UseAspNetCore();

        });
    services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.ClaimsIdentity.UserNameClaimType = OpenIddictConstants.Claims.Username;
        options.ClaimsIdentity.UserIdClaimType = OpenIddictConstants.Claims.Subject;
        options.ClaimsIdentity.RoleClaimType = OpenIddictConstants.Claims.Role;
        options.ClaimsIdentity.EmailClaimType = OpenIddictConstants.Claims.Email;
        options.ClaimsIdentity.SecurityStampClaimType = "secret_value";
    });
```

And resource server configuraion is :

```
  .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
    {
        options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";
        options.Authority = (env.IsProduction() ? "https://" : "http://") + openIDConnectSettings["Authority"];
        options.ClientId = openIDConnectSettings["ClientId"];
        options.ClientSecret = openIDConnectSettings["ClientSecret"];
        options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Token;
        options.UsePkce = true;
        options.Scope.Add("profile");
        options.SaveTokens = true;
        options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    });
```

Comment: You should [not use the password grant](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-security-topics-13#section-3.4).

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden I'm using password grant, but my auth server is apart from MVC and I'd like to implent login page in mvc side rather that auth server